# Is there a 'choice' Java annotation equivalent to <xs:choice>?

Tags: java, web-services, validation, xsd, annotations

I am looking to field validate a web service request by only allowing one of two different fields in the request. I know from past experience from using xsd that you can have something like this to only allow either FieldOne *or* FieldTwo:

```
<xs:complexType name="SomeType">
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="FieldOne" type="target:FieldOneType"/>
        <xs:element name="FieldTwo" type="target:FieldTwoType"/>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

I would like to do the same using Java annotations. I am currently using annotations for limiting field length (@Digits) and null checks (@NotNull).

Is there something I can use for a 'choice'?

Thanks for any help.

**UPDATE:** Basically I am looking for some way of only allowing one of two different fields to be entered in a web service request without having to do this validation in my code manually. I am currently using [bean validation annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html) to limit field lengths and to determine whether a field is mandatory or optional e.g.:

```
@NotNull(message="Field cannot be empty")
@Size(max = 6, message = "Field length is too long")
private String fieldOne;
```

I would like to be able to say that the user can only enter *either* fieldOne or fieldTwo, but not both. Is this possible through annotations or am I stuck to writing this validation in my code?

Comment: Do you mean that there are 2 fields (`fieldOne` and `fieldTwo`) in your class but only one of them allow to have value?

Comment: Yes that's what I want.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please see whether it can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited:**

To validate either one field has value but not other, I think you can use a custom validator at class level. Following is the idea:

1.
Create interface for your annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = ChoiceValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface Choice {

    String[] fields();

    String message() default "{Choice.message}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

2.
Create a implementation of `ConstraintValidator` to check the value to be validated is in `fields` inside `Choice` annotation:

```
public class ChoiceValidator
        implements ConstraintValidator<Choice, Object> {

    private List<String> fields;

    @Override
    public void initialize(final Choice choice) {
        fields = Arrays.asList(choice.fields());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final Object value, final ConstraintValidatorContext ctx) {

        int nonNullFieldCount = 0;
        for (String field : fields) {
            try {
                final String fieldValue = BeanUtils.getProperty(value, field);
                if (fieldValue != null) {
                    nonNullFieldCount++;
                }
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        return nonNullFieldCount == 1;
    }

}
```

After that, you can use it something like:

```
@Choice(fields= {"fieldOne", "fieldTwo"})
public  class Foo {

    String fieldOne;

    String fieldTwo;

}
```

---

**Original:**

I am not sure I really get you mean, but looks like you want a validation on the `Class` types of a `Object` field. If there is the case, you may try to create your custom annotation and `ConstraintValidator` to do so. Following is the idea:

1.
Create interface for your annotation:

```
public @interface Choice {

    Class<?>[] types();

}
```

2.
Create a implementation of `ConstraintValidator` to check the value to be validated is in `types` inside `Choice` annotation:

```
public class ChoiceValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Choice, Object> {

    private List<Class<?>> clazzes;

    @Override
    public void initialize(Choice choice) {
        clazzes = Arrays.asList(choice.types());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        for (Class<?> clazz : clazzes) {
            if (value.getClass().equals(clazz)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

After that, you can use it something like:

```
@Choice(types = {FieldOneType.class, FieldTwoType.class})
public class Foo ｛

    Object someType;

}
```

Hope this can help.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This isn't exactly what I am looking for but it has helped me understand the problem better.

Comment: Can you provide more details about your requirement to the question? This may help me and others to come up with a more suitable solution.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for your work on this. This has solved my problem :)